# Unreachable error while open website in WebView

Tags: android, webview

When I tried to open the web link that includes "#!" using Andorid WebView, I am getting this error.

net:Err_Address_Unreachable

I think it is url includes specific characters. But it works in web browsewr. 
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: show the URL structure. You probably need to urlencode some part of the url.

Comment: https://screendynamics.com/webapp/touch/#!/home/?uid=260
For example, you can see #!.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Do you know how to encode some part of url?